# Kitchen drawer soft-closer - whose company logo is this?

Tags: kitchens

The soft close on my pull out larder has broken and I'm struggling to identify it for obtain a replacement. Does anyone recognise this logo?

The only other identifying mark on it is a number 136685 POM

[image]

Full thing, as requested:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome.    I wasn't able to locate the K-logo, but "POM" is a type of plastic ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyoxymethylene)), so that's probably the recycle code.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Zoom out so we can see the whole damper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brand is [KESSEBÖHMER](https://www.kesseboehmer.world/en/) (their [US store](https://www.cleverstorage.com/)). I can't find that exact part number you provided, so maybe that is not the actual part number of the retail product.

Comment: Well done sir; https://www.clever-storage-shop.de/produkt/softstopp-plus-einzugsdaempfer-2/